# - Syntax error on token ".8", . expected

Tags: java, android, eclipse, syntax, token

i have a problems with that error and i dont know why, please help me. Thx
its a sourcecode, and wen i try to change the names, eclipse give me that error.

```
package com.8ctasoft.LeagueofSounds; ****<-----The error is here****

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;


public class Glasssmasher extends Activity {

    Surface view;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //full screen
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Any idea?

Comment: Read here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Comment: aand....a possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243316/java-code-convention-for-package-names

Comment: @kocko These links address *conventions* not syntax.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because a [Java identifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) cannot start with a number.