# What does the "com" mean in Maven group id? Is it necessary?

Tags: java, maven

In a school project, we are supposed to use maven enabled project. Maven is a great system for managing dependencies, so I'm quite happy I'll finally learn to use it.

However I already started project as Netbeans project and I'm now struggling how to reconfigure it. When creating the project IDE advised me to call it `com.myname`. This resulted in redundant empty folder `com/myname/{sources start here}`. Windows explorer isn't as smart as GitHub and doesn't skip empty folder which makes it very annoying.

I'm strongly considering that I'll call the project just `myname`. Is that valid? What are the risks of breaking this convention? Where did this convention come from and what does `com` abbreviation mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do you really use your reverse domain for package naming in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189209/do-you-really-use-your-reverse-domain-for-package-naming-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`com` is part of a reverse domain. So if your domain is

`somecompany.com` your maven artefacts should be named `com.somecompany.awesomeThingy`

This makes sure we don't get name clashes when I publish my

```
com.someothercompany.awesomeThingy
```

This is also the [naming convention for java packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189209/do-you-really-use-your-reverse-domain-for-package-naming-in-java).

All this doesn't really matter as long as your maven repos are private. Once you intend to publish artifacts to maven central though, there are [rules enforcing that you name artifacts using a domain you control](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/choosing-your-coordinates.html).

And of course there are other TLDs around, so `org`, `de` and many more are options too.

Comment: That seems to imply that one must be a domain owner to publish libraries.

Comment: I'm not sure how strict these rules are, and if there are exceptions, but basically yes.

Comment: If this is for a school project, you most likely do not want to publish your project to Maven Central.

Comment: @TomášZato Not necessarily. If your project is hosted on GitHub then make your package `com.github.awesomethingy` as long as it is unique there should be no problems.

Comment: @ArtB I think the better option would be: io.github.<username> because via github pages you actually control that domain.

Comment: @JensSchauder you might move of the project and someone else might pickup the mantle. The domain should reflect the project not you. Also the precedent for this has be established under [`net.sf`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/) and [`net.sourceforge`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sourceforge/) ([SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/) was essentially a predecessor to GitHub).

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is valid. Eclipse recommends this, because it usally makes sense for an organization. For a school project, not so much.

Anyway, this is a common convention in the Java world, you should get used to it :)

Comment: The thing is that I'm in Czech Republic and I own no domain. At that point, using `com` makes really no sense.

Comment: You can use `cz` of course :) I myself always use `hu.meskobalazs` for my projects. And no, I don't have this domain.

Comment: Further more, if I have site on webhosting subdomain, would I use something like `com.freesites.myproject...`?

Comment: You could. You don't have to map to a real URL, two whole point is to come up with a globally unique identification, so you can avoid any potential name collisions with external dependencies. Otherwise, it is totally your call.

Answer (score 1):

It's just part of a Java package name.

Package names in Java look like domain names, but in reverse order. For example if someone is working for "somecompany.com" then he or she will usually use the package name `com.somecompany.someproduct`.

This is just the convention in the Java world. It's not required to adhere to this convention.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it just a Java Convention.
Ideally com refers to Commercial, which is used for commercial purpose.

You can use anything instead of com, like org. or edu.

```
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
```

But going forward in your future, you will certainly need to follow the same code structure. So, how about practicing from college project itself.